# Mail recieved late EC2 PHP

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2, smtp

I have an application running on an EC2 Instance.
In parts of the application there needs to be sent out notifications to users via email. I use PHP's native mail() function.

The problem is that it does not seem to be very stable. I did some testing last night, and found that some emails were received instantly, but some seemed to wait around for quite a while.

I triggered two notifications within a minute, and within seconds i received the notification for the second event, but it took up to half an hour for the first event notification to appear in my inbox.

Here are the email headers for the one that came in late:

```
Delivered-To: ----@gmail.com
Received: by 10.140.107.75 with SMTP id g69csp40419qgf; Wed, 3 Dec 2014 16:12:00 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.194.108.162 with SMTP id hl2mr11475479wjb.102.1417651919645; Wed, 03 Dec 2014 16:11:59 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <apache@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.localdomain>
Received: from ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.localdomain (ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. [xx.xx.xx.xx])
by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g6si19323730wjy.43.2014.12.03.16.11.59
for <----@gmail.com>; Wed, 03 Dec 2014 16:11:59 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: none (google.com: apache@ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.localdomain does not designate permitted sender hosts) client-ip=xx.xx.xx.xx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=none (google.com: apache@ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.localdomain does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mail=apache@ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.localdomain; dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: by ip-172-31-19-221.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 48 id CABF521F29; Wed,  3 Dec 2014 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)
To: ---- <----@gmail.com>
Subject: Test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 500:Notifier.class.php
From: ---- <----@gmail.com>
Message-Id: <20141203233835.CABF521F29@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.localdomain>
Date: Wed,  3 Dec 2014 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)
```

I cant figure out what is causing this, so if anyone has an idea where the problem could be, answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: you realize that php has absolutely NOTHING to do with actual delivery? php's job is to walk your letter down to the street corner and toss it into the mailbox. If the postal service is slow, that's not php's problem.

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

From the line below, it looks like your PHP script created the message at 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)

```
Date: Wed,  3 Dec 2014 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)
```

Then, from this line below, postfix running on the same host immediately acknowledged receipt of the message from PHP (by way of the mail() function):

```
Received: by ip-172-31-19-221.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 48 id CABF521F29; Wed,  3 Dec 2014 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)
```

The problem seems to be in the next hop.  It looks like Postfix is configured to relay mail through Amazon's SMTP service.  However, adjusting for the timezone differnces, Amazon's SMTP server did not receive the message until approximately 33 minutes later:

```
Received: from ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.localdomain (ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. [xx.xx.xx.xx])by mx.google.com with ESMTP id g6si19323730wjy.43.2014.12.03.16.11.59
```

for <----@gmail.com>; Wed, 03 Dec 2014 16:11:59 -0800 (PST)

So, the delay was in postfix on your local host getting the message over to Amazon's SMTP relaying server.  It's possible that Amazon's server deferred receipt of the message form your postfix server several times, so the delay may have been caused by postfix having to requeue the message and re-attempt delivery several times, until it finally succeeded 33 minutes later.  If you are able to get to the logs on your postfix server, these might shed some light on what caused the delay.

Part of the problem looks like it might be that you are setting the sender address in the FROM: headers of the message, but you are not setting the envelope sender.  It looks like a default envelope sender is being used (apache@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.localdomain), which is obviously not a valid email address, and it looks like this may be causing problems with the SPF check.  Amazon's SMTP server may be deferring delivery of the message for this reason.  You might want to set the envelope sender, and see if this solves the problem.  This syntax should do the trick:

```
$to = "to@to.com";
$from = "from@from.com";
$subject = "subject";
$message = "this is the message body";

$headers = "From: $from"; 
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from);
```

Comment: I have an ec2 instance that is configured to Sydney time and the server is set up to run in the UTC time format. The emails are queued to jobs table in an ec2 instance and then send immediately. But the mails are not received instantaneously but after one or two hours of time. Is it because of the same issue?